# How i can in jsfiddle look to console?

Tags: jsfiddle

I can't find where i can look to logs of console in jsfiddle. It possible do in this service?

```
console.log()
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7z4f/5/)
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get console inside jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130610/how-to-get-console-inside-jsfiddle)

Comment: JSfiddle has just released his own console feature: Go into the `Settings -> Console` to activate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the log in your normal browser console window. All console.log() output from jsfiddle is passed to the browser as a normal js script does.

You may check it here:

```
console.log("hello");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/srijithv/eXW7p/

Comment: Yes, i can look it. But i can't select best answer 9 minutes. Thanks, for answer!