# How to get console inside jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, console, jsfiddle

How can I get the console to show in a fiddle on JSfiddle.com?

I recently saw a fiddle that had the console embedded in the fiddle, anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Which fiddle was that?

Comment: Any chance that the fiddle just did something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/FL4XL/

Comment: I believe they removed it recently.  Try codepen.io instead.

Comment: No it was an actual console inside the fiddle, I am going to go through my browser history to find the example.

Comment: @VtoCorleone this is what I wanted https://jsfiddle.net/c42vd3m9/1/ CodeBroJohn answered it. Super useful

Comment: @Octopus see this example https://jsfiddle.net/c42vd3m9/1/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a web service

Comment: @EvanCarroll JS Fiddle is *a software tool commonly used by programmers* so it's on topic on this site. Ref. [help/on-topic].

Comment: This question is not clear enough when I searched this I just wanted a JavaScript solution, not a specific library console using jQuery. This is not a bad thing; however, maybe include more information like your jsfiddle reference to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print Var in JsFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382200/print-var-in-jsfiddle)

Comment: @KyleMit the original question was different although the answers were simular. It's not duped, the original queation was more of an xy queastion and was not searchable in the same context. Also, it is for 2 different versions of fiddle.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith, I here ya.  I don't think duplicate here is a bad sounding word or means there's anything wrong with this question. At this point, both questions have similar answers and both just simply refer to whatever the current version of fiddle happens to be.  Plenty of votes on this issue agrees that you definitely hit the searchability piece with the titling, which is why using a dupe to forward users to a single canonical answer is a good strategy for folks who hit this issue in the future.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith,  I hope that makes sense.  I didn't mean to suggest anything was wrong with this question itself, just that it's nearly identical to the other and users who find one helpful will likely find both helpful, would you agree - or am I missing something?

Comment: @KyleMit The linked question is asking **"How would I print something to the result screen in JsFiddle from my JavaScript. I can't use document.write(), it doesn't allow it, neither print."** in the newer versions on JSfiddle `document.write()` is allowed without console. My question is specifically asking how to embed a console into JSfiddle.

Comment: @KyleMit While both answers, answer each question, the answer below is more correct for current versions of fiddles, no external links needed. "Possible duplicate" 's get voted on to be removed and is not the correct method for sharing a link to another answer, you could have simply linked the other question in the comments without voting it as a dup.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith, duplicate questions do not get "removed" if they have a non-zero score.  All the points and votes earned on this question will continue to exist and even increment as people find it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

1. Expand the JavaScript panel
2. Select **jQuery Edge**
3. Select **Firebug Lite**.

[image: Example of Settings]

Which should add an inline console to the bottom of the results tab

[image: Example of Output]

Comment: it should simply be included that you need to have your javascript set to use the jQuery edge library or a subset of jQuery to see the firebug lite option, else it will not show up readily.

Comment: The answer [bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43484981/1259637) looks like a better solution if you don't want to use JQuery.

Comment: This solution requires you to use jQuery, not vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 100):

pretty simple one..

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/op9wumdz/)

[github](https://github.com/eu81273/jsfiddle-console)

Just add the following URL to External Resources in jsfiddle, you will see console.log and console.error in the result screen.

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/eu81273/jsfiddle-console/console.js
```

Comment: i was looking for this and this does the job. Although to view the object graph in the log, instead of [object Object], just press F12 and see the logs in the browser console.

Comment: great! although it's still printing the ugly [object Object] and it prints three dots for nested objects. Nevertheless it is very helpful in some cases. I'm using the web browser console now though.

Comment: this is true only for empty HTML (only javascript)

Answer (score 36):

- click on that arrow next to **JavaScript**
- and as **FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS** select **No-Libary (Pure JS)**
- paste your **`console.log('foo');`** in JS box
- under **Resources** add **`https://rawgit.com/eu81273/jsfiddle-console/master/console.js`**

  - or: under **Resources** add **`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/eu81273/jsfiddle-console/console.js`**
- and run your script hitting that Play button

[image]

Comment: The **gif** is really helpful.

Comment: @Ruben, except that this answer appeared before the top voted one so deserves the credit! + the gif really helps!!

Answer (score 21):

I couldn't find any option for selecting the Firebug extension in the JavaScript gear option, and I didn't want to add external links/libraries, but there is another *simple* solution.

#### You can use your browser's built in console

[image: Dev Tools Console]

Comment: I am surprised to see how this answer is downvoted. The answer seems to be pretty realistic, simple and non redundant. Any explanation?? Atleast, I am trying to suggest other alternatives and possible solutions.

Comment: I am sorry the downvote is upsetting for you. Downvote is nothing to do with your method - it's because this isn't an answer to the question. It's a suggestion of an alternative and that would be better placed as a comment to OP question. I cannot remove the downvote unless you update the answer and I would only remove it if the update made this an answer to the question or provided a reasonable set of reasons why this method is a viable option above what OP asked for.

Comment: Using the Browser's built in Console, I can see the results of `console.log()` as you demonstrate, but I still cannot interact with variables in the jsfiddle. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Upvote, because I dont see the option for the firebug extension either, the simplest solution is to just hit F12

Comment: The approach works but is not perfect. The console logs appear (obviously) on the built in console but Jsfiddle does not render the webpage (fiddle) itself properly after that. What is needed is a dedicated console pane inside jsfiddle (similar the one provided by other playgrounds like JSBin, CodePen etc.). I noticed that the feature is in-fact under development in their roadmap (https://trello.com/b/LakLkQBW/jsfiddle-roadmap)

Comment: @AnshumanManral I don't care about when and where it is going to be there, until solution works. I don't see any reason to downvote though!

Comment: Worth adding- go into the options on jsFiddle and switch to tabbed view, so you don't have HTML and CSS panes taking up space even though you're not using them. Set the CSS to `* { background-color:black}` so you don't have a big white box on an otherwise dark page.

Answer (score 15):

works fine... [here](http://jsfiddle.net/maky/cm3kjm29/2/)

```
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";

console = {
    log: function (text) {
        $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
    }
};
console.log("Hello Console")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your answer literally answers what I was asking but I wasn't clear on my question, so I will give you a plus 1, here is a link to a fiddle that shows what I was talking about https://jsfiddle.net/c42vd3m9/1/

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solutions worked for me, since I needed an *interactive console* to be able to dynamically set a variable when testing reactivity in Vue.js.

So I switched to [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/), which has a [an interactive console](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/editor/console/) scoped to your application.

[image: CodePen Example]

Comment: I also noticed that I was unable to interact with the DOM using jQuery and the native browser console in Js Fiddle. With CodePen I was able to open the native console and select my html elements using jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to embed a *virtual console* inside of any web page...

#### 1. Firebug Lite Debugger  <sup>[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/w6gf1kp3/)</sup>

Include the following script from [Firebug Lite](https://github.com/firebug/firebug-lite/), served via [raw.githack.com](https://raw.githack.com/):

[**`https://rawcdn.githack.com/firebug/firebug-lite/firebug1.5/build/firebug-lite-debug.js`**](https://rawcdn.githack.com/firebug/firebug-lite/firebug1.5/build/firebug-lite-debug.js)

[image: firebug]

#### 2. Stack Snippets Virtual Console  <sup>[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/z9nx30kL/)</sup>

Include the following script from [/u/canon](https://github.com/gh-canon/stack-snippet-console), used in [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491/209031):

[**`https://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js`**](https://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js)

[image: Stack Snippets]

#### 3. Add jsFiddle Console  <sup>[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/we14p3L0/)</sup>

Include the following script from [eu81273](https://github.com/eu81273/jsfiddle-console), served via [raw.githack.com](https://raw.githack.com/) :

[**`https://raw.githack.com/eu81273/jsfiddle-console/master/console.js`**](https://rawcdn.githack.com/eu81273/jsfiddle-console/eab2695cc293b9a24290953a713b2191358845bf/console.js)

[image: jsFiddle Console]

#### 4. Roll You Own

Here's a trivial implementation that wraps the existing `console.log` call and then dumps out the [prettified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510/1366033) [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4633130/1366033) using `document.write`:

```js
var oldLog = window.console.log
window.console.log = function(...args) {
    document.write(JSON.stringify(args, null, 2));
    oldLog.apply(this, args);
}

console.log("String", 44, {name: "Kyle", age: 30}, [1,2,3])
```

#### Further Reading

- [Print Var in JsFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17382200/1366033)

Answer (score 3):

For future reference: the jsfiddle-console from answer was exactly what I needed when teaching a class on JavaScript. However I found it to be too limited to be of any actual use in this situation. So I made my own.

Maybe it will serve anyone here.

Just add the CDN-version to the resources of jsFiddle:

```
https://unpkg.com/html-console-output
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Brutac/e5nsp2mu/

GitHub: https://github.com/karimayachi/html-console-output

Comment: Pretty cool. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party but just wanted to mention that JSfiddle has just released the new console feature. Just turn it on in the Settings if it doesn't work for you.

[image]

Still in beta but hey... no more annoying workarounds.